# Executing Stored proc from UDF

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, user-defined-functions

is it possible to execute a stored procedure inside a user defined function in Oracle 10g database?
If yes, could you please give en example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. See for example [The last example in Oracle® Database SQL Reference
10g Release 1 (10.1) Create function](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_5009.htm)
The example uses a package but can also be a stored procedure. No problems.
What is your problem?